# aroundCollectCarrierRates is not working for Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping (Warning: Missing argument 1 ...)

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, plugin

Here is my `plugin` code:

**app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php**

```
public function aroundCollectCarrierRates($subject, $proceed, $carrierCode, $request)
    {
        $result = $proceed();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $gid=$customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
            $group_info=$this->helper->getGroupData($gid);
            //var_dump($group_info);exit;
        }

        $result->append($group_info);

        return $result;
    }
```

But this is not working.

I get the following error:

```
[2016-09-20 11:46:55] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectCarrierRates(), called in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 74 and defined in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 240 in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(240): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Missing argumen...', '/mage2/shipping...', 240, Array)
#1 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectCarrierRates()
#2 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->___callParent('collectCarrierR...', Array)
#3 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Shippin...', 'collectCarrierR...', Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor), Array, 'shipping_restri...')
#4 mage2/shipping/app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php(98): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#5 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Test\Shipping\Plugin\Shipping->aroundCollectCarrierRates(Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'dhl', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#6 mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor.php(91): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->___callPlugins('collectCarrierR...', Array, Array)
#7 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(209): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->collectCarrierRates('dhl', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#8 mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor.php(76): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#9 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(995): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#10 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(936): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->requestShippingRates()
#11 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php(161): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->collectShippingRates()
#12 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php(265): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Shipping->collect(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total))
#13 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(273): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collectAddressTotals(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#14 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(213): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->getShippingMethods(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Array)
#15 [internal function]: Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->estimateByExtendedAddress('12', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#16 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#18 mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#21 mage2/shipping/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#22 {main}

Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-57e121af66e20; Message: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectCarrierRates(), called in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 74 and defined in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 240 in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 mage2/shipping/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
[2016-09-20 11:46:56] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectCarrierRates(), called in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 74 and defined in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 240 in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(240): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Missing argumen...', '/mage2/shipping...', 240, Array)
#1 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectCarrierRates()
#2 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->___callParent('collectCarrierR...', Array)
#3 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Shippin...', 'collectCarrierR...', Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor), Array, 'shipping_restri...')
#4 mage2/shipping/app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php(98): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#5 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Test\Shipping\Plugin\Shipping->aroundCollectCarrierRates(Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'dhl', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#6 mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor.php(91): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->___callPlugins('collectCarrierR...', Array, Array)
#7 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(209): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->collectCarrierRates('dhl', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#8 mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor.php(76): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#9 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(995): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))
#10 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(936): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->requestShippingRates()
#11 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php(161): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->collectShippingRates()
#12 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php(265): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Shipping->collect(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total))
#13 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(273): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collectAddressTotals(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#14 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(213): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->getShippingMethods(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Array)
#15 [internal function]: Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->estimateByExtendedAddress('12', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#16 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#18 mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#21 mage2/shipping/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#22 {main}

Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-57e121b09b20f; Message: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectCarrierRates(), called in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 74 and defined in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 240 in mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 mage2/shipping/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 mage2/shipping/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 mage2/shipping/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
```

What is the issue with my code?

Comment: Any one know answer for this question ?

Answer (score 1):

The `$proceed()` closure needs the same parameters than the original method. In this case you have to change it to:

```
$proceed($carrierCode, $request);
```

By the way, since you call it at the beginning without changing parameters, an **after** plugin is more suitable.

Comment: Yes, you are right after plugin is more suitable, but i need to get all shipping method in chackout/cart page for set all method. So i use around plugin @fschmengler.

Comment: Thanks for help.. Now error solved, but i can't got proper output for me.